# How can I be notified when a background process terminates in Perl?

Tags: perl, fork

I wrote a Perl program which forks and calls a background program in the child process and has a endless while loop which does some stuff in the parent process. Now the while loop should be left when the background program in the child process terminates:

```
$pid = fork();
if ( !$pid ) {
    exec( "program args" );
} else {
    while ( 1 ) {
        # do something

        # needs help: if program terminated, break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `fork` gives your parent process the child's PID (which you dutifully retrieve in your code). This is precisely so the parent can look after the child.

To leave the loop when it terminates, you can use `kill 0 $pid` to check whether the  child still exists. See `perldoc -f kill`.

Comment: The problem is that the process is becoming a zombie, so the command still returns true.

Comment: It works though, when setting $SIG{CHLD}='IGNORE' (see next answer)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a signal handler to take care of CHLD signal the parent process is sent when the child process exits. (See `perldoc perlipc` for more details about signal handling in perl.)

You can do something like below in the else loop to reap the child process.

```
...
} else {
    $SIG{CHLD} = \&reaper
}

# hash to store exit status of child processes
our %child;    
sub reaper {
    my $x;
    while (($x = waitpid(-1,WNOHANG)) >0) {
        $child{$x} = $? >> 8;
    }
}
```

or you can set `$SIG{CHLD}='IGNORE'` to not worry about child processes becoming zombies.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I combined it with the tip above

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application you can check from time to time if the child ended and the parent can finish then. You can use posix waitpid() with WNOHANG to do a no-blocking wait, or signals to check if your child is still running, or you can use pipes (check when it gets closed).   Personally I would use waitpid(). There is a very good explanation with examples in perlipc.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, exec() is blocking, so it wouldn't return before the program quits, but I may be wrong.

Comment: -1 No, the program uses `fork` before, so only one child process will use `exec`, which is just right.